# Java - Checking if string is in another string

Tags: java, string, substring

Say I have this...

```
 String one = "No";
 String two = "Yes, No, Maybe";

 if (one.contains(two))
 {
   System.out.println("yay");
 }
```

When I run this, I thought yay would have printed because String one is in String two, but it didn't. Is there another way of checking if a string is in part of another string, or am I just missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is reversed. Try this:

```
if (two.contains(one))
    . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the check it would work `if (two.contains(one))`

From [**API**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
```

> returns: true if this string contains s, false otherwise

**In your case :**

> returns: true if two contains one, false otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You just have it backwards.

```
String one = "No";
String two = "Yes, No, Maybe";

if (two.contains(one))
{
  System.out.println("yay");
}
```